# auto detect segmentation fault and re-run if segmentation fault occurs

Tags: bash, scripting

I have a script `get_new_GMC.sh` that contains this line:

```
./casm.x < input_to_casm.txt
```

However, sometimes we might get a segmentation fault (and sometimes we do not)... Sometimes it would have the error:

> get_new_GMC.sh: line 156: 72577 Segmentation fault: 11  ./casm.x <
>   input_to_casm.txt

How could I change my script so that whenever a segmentation fault occurs, I would just rerun `./casm.x < input_to_casm.txt` again? Thank you.

Comment: If possible, then you should really try to fix the crash instead of just working around it.

Comment: As for the workaround, read about [Bash traps](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_12_02.html).